# Image Size Problem

Tags: magento-2.1, cache

There is a 400KB image1.jpg image in my `/httpdocs/pub/media/XXX/slideshow/cache/1900x730/s/w/image1.jpg`
folder

I'm decreasing the size of this image to 200KB with Photoshop and uploading it to the same directory with FTP program.

It looks ok, but if I open the homepage and check the same directory, it returns to 400kb again.

I know it's about caching problem, but couldn't find the ssh command to solve it.

Could you help me? I'm using Magento 2.1.7 with Ubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete folder `/var/cache` and `/var/page_cache` and check it.

In Magento backend :

system > Cache management flush all cache also clear browser cache

Answer (score 0):

Clear your cache, and then try again.

To clear your cache (Magento 1.x):

- Head to Magento admin panel
- System -> Cache Management
- Flush Cache Storage, Flush Magento Cache